# GLFW thread handling?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm making a GL renderer in a window. The program itself works fine but when I "thread" the render loop( as I have done for a networking class so I was guessing it should work), the program opens and work for couple seconds before crashing, like if the memory was being full ?

look in the main to see my problem

```
class MyWorld {

public:

  GLFWwindow *window;
  std::thread thread;

  MyWorld() {

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(300, 300, "OUTPUT", nullptr, nullptr);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glViewport(0, 0, 300, 300);

    glewInit();

  }

  void run() {

    while (1) {

      glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

      glfwPollEvents();

      glClearColor(sin(glfwGetTime()), 0, 0, 1 ); // BG COLOR
      glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

      glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    }

  }

  void threadrun() {

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
    thread = std::thread(&MyWorld::run, this);
    thread.detach();

  }

};

int main() {

  MyWorld world;

  // world.run(); // this works fine

  world.threadrun(); // this doesn't


  while (1) { continue; }


}
```

Comment: Do you get a message when your program crashes?  What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: I'm not using any debuger. No message when it crashes

Comment: The first step in fixing this problem is [using your debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: yes you(and the article you pointed me to) are certaincly right I tend to take a bit of time to accept the obvious. I'm wotking with atom so no debugger here i think I have to understand how gcc debugger works and thats another problem ... My case is not a bug of forgotten ";" or else , I've came up with a reproductible case , it's a real logical question. I'm sure some expert arround would spot my problem in seconds

Comment: I get no difference from debuger DBG when I'm run the normal or the threaded version, I get several "new threads"

Comment: thanks for the reply @httpdigest. So that mean what I want to do is impossible ? seems crazy to me ?...

Comment: hey . I am now ;) can you correct my code so it works though ? I'm having trouble still getting what should go where. I only thread the render loop as you say so it should work ? : I have been fighting with this for 2 days now ... ^^

Comment: Ok thx ! unfortunatly I can't start chat for being new user ...  so I've did the changes you told me and many other combination with no luck, though I feel like this is indeed my problem ... and reading the docs are not so clear to me ... I'm gonna keep looking in this direction.

Comment: @user1906731, Which platforms do you want to target with this application? There are some differences in the way each OS handles windows & multi-threaded GUI. It is normally safest to create the `GLFWwindow` instance and use **all** GLFW functions from the `main()` thread. You *can* multi-thread the **window handling** on some platforms, but that is an entirely separate thing from multi-threading the **rendering**. You may call OpenGL functions from any thread you wish, that has nothing to do with GLFW.